# PHP min() function regarding decimals

Tags: php, arrays, decimal, min

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","eurusd");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$highs = array();
$lows = array();
$timestore = array();
$time = '23:00'; // start
for ($i = 0; $i <= 120; $i++)
{
    $prev = date('H:i', strtotime($time)); 
    $next = strtotime('+1mins', strtotime($time)); 
    $time = date('H:i', $next); // format the next time
    array_push($timestore, $prev);
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT * FROM eurusd2009 where date='"."2009-01-06"."'and time='".$timestore[$i]."'
    ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    array_push($highs, $row[3]); //push highs to array
    array_push($lows, $row[4]); //push lows to array
}
print_r($timestore);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($highs);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($lows);
echo "<hr>";
$maxvaluehighs = max($highs);
$maxvaluelows = max($lows);

$minvaluehighs = min($highs);
$minvaluelows = min($lows);

echo $maxvaluehighs; //works
echo $maxvaluelows; //works

echo $minvaluehighs; //does not work
echo $minvaluelows; //does not work
```

array example

`$highs = 
    Array ( [0] => 1.353800 [1] => 1.353300 [2] => 1.352700 [3] => 1.353100 [4] =>           1.352900 [5] => 1.352600 [6] => 1.352500 [7] => 1.352500 [8] => 1.352600 [9] => 1.353300 [10] => 1.352700 [11] => 1.352800 [12] => 1.352900 [13] => 1.353000 [14] => [15] => 1.353200 [16] => 1.353600 [17] => 1.353900 [18] => 1.353600 [19] => 1.353700 [20] => 1.353600 [21] => 1.353600 [22] => 1.353200 [23] => 1.353200 [24] => 1.353400 [25] => 1.353200 [26] => 1.353100 [27] => 1.353400 [28] => 1.353300 [29] => 1.353300 [30] => 1.353400 [31] => 1.353400 [32] => 1.353400 [33] => 1.353600 [34] => 1.353800 [35] => 1.353800 [36] => 1.353700 [37] => 1.353700 [38] => 1.353700 [39] => 1.353700 [40] => 1.353500 [41] => 1.353000 [42] => 1.353100 [43] => 1.353000 [44] => 1.352600 [45] => 1.352500 [46] => 1.352400 [47] => 1.352400 [48] => 1.352300 [49] => 1.352100 [50] => 1.352200 [51] => 1.352100 [52] => 1.352100 [53] => 1.352500 [54] => 1.352600 [55] => 1.352600 [56] => 1.351800 [57] => 1.352000 [58] => 1.352000 [59] => 1.351900 [60] => 1.355600 [61] => 1.354800 [62] => 1.355400 [63] => 1.355300 [64] => 1.354700 [65] => 1.354700 [66] => 1.354800 [67] => 1.354800 [68] => 1.354900 [69] => 1.355000 [70] => 1.354900 [71] => 1.354900 [72] => 1.355400 [73] => 1.355500 [74] => 1.355600 [75] => 1.355600 [76] => 1.354500 [77] => 1.353900 [78] => 1.353700 [79] => 1.352100 [80] => 1.351400 [81] => 1.351000 [82] => 1.351300 [83] => 1.351400 [84] => 1.351500 [85] => 1.351400 [86] => 1.352600 [87] => 1.352600 [88] => 1.352600 [89] => 1.352700 [90] => 1.352400 [91] => 1.352200 [92] => 1.351700 [93] => 1.351300 [94] => 1.351200 [95] => 1.351400 [96] => 1.351200 [97] => 1.351000 [98] => 1.351900 [99] => 1.352000 [100] => 1.352200 [101] => 1.352000 [102] => 1.351300 [103] => 1.351200 [104] => 1.351700 [105] => 1.351600 [106] => 1.351900 [107] => 1.352100 [108] => 1.351900 [109] => 1.352100 [110] => 1.352600 [111] => 1.352700 [112] => 1.352800 [113] => 1.352400 [114] => 1.352500 [115] => 1.352400 [116] => 1.351800 [117] => 1.351800 [118] => 1.352100 [119] => 1.352000 [120] => 1.351700 )`

Hello, I am a beginner at this. I'm basically trying to get the mins and maxs from an array using php. For now only the max seems to be working, but min isn't. I tried searching for a solution online but I couldn't find one, and I have very little idea what to try next. I tried using:

```
 echo min(array_map('floatval',$highs));
```

but have had no luck with it. Thanks.

Comment: smaller array examples would be appreciated

Comment: What values are you getting for your mins?

Comment: no values, thats why im confused :S

Comment: @user3294895: What *are* you getting though?

Comment: What does "no values" mean?

Comment: maxvaluehighs: 1.355600, maxvaluelows:1.355400 minvaluehighs: minvaluelows: , html empty space arent i supposed to be getting a value like the max

Comment: alternatively, you could just `sort` the arrays and `array_shift` and `array_pop` for min/max values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of your values in the array that is passed to min function is NULL, min will return null. Take care of that situation in your query by adding columnname is not null

```
min(1.2, 2, null, -1)  // yields NULL not -1
```

so in your script, do this to pass the null values

```
if (!empty($row[4])) {
   array_push($lows, $row[4]); //push lows to array
}
```

Comment: thank you had a null, i will make sure to check that next time :)

Comment: You are welcome. PHP has such tricky functions (such as empty(0) is true but empty(0.0) is false ) so before kicking yourself, just know that it may be PHP function that is the problem and check documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
$highs = Array (1.353800, 1.353300, 1.352700, NULL);

// if you want to leave only scalar values
$highs = array_filter($highs, 'is_scalar');

usort($highs, function($a, $b) {
    return bccomp($a, $b);
});

$min = reset($highs);
```

Read more how to compare float: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php